# Substring another function

Tags: php, substring

```
<input type="hidden" name="com_link" value="?dir=<?php echo 'gallery/'.urldecode($curr_image['dir']); ?>&pic=<?php echo substr(urldecode($curr_image['filename']), 0, -4); ?>">
```

`substr(urldecode($curr_image['filename']), 0, -4);` I want to send filename without `.jpg`

Comment: -1 Your question is very poorly described. What do you want to do? What have you tried and what results did you get?

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant for future users as well, not just for your own free support. This question is useless to future visitors because it is impossible to understand what you are asking.

Comment: I have filename in variable and I want to see only name of image without .jpg, .png extensions.So I used `echo substr(urldecode($curr_image['filename']), 0, -4);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few methods you could use to get the path without the extension.

One would be to use PHP's `substr()` with [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/strrpos):

```
$image = urldecode($curr_image['filename']);
$name = substr($image, 0, strrpos($image, '.'));
```

This will get a substring of the `$image` up to the last `.`.

Another method, if you know that the extension will always be 4-characters long (including the `.`), is to just chop off the last 4 characters:

```
$image = urldecode($curr_image['filename']);
$length = strlen($image);
$name = substr($image, 0, $length - 4);
```

This last method appears to be what you were trying to do to begin with.

Comment: i've used your first method several times cool nice one

Comment: No problem, glad it works (^_^)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u try http://php.net/basename

```
<?php echo basename($curr_image['filename'], '.jpg'); ?>
```

Comment: what if the image is `.png` or `.gif`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  urlencode(pathinfo($curr_image['filename'], PATHINFO_FILENAME));
```